# Disable notifications in Android

Tags: android

I have a live streaming app where you can be recording for hours and when the user receives a text message or a phone call, the vibration is trnaslated into sound and rippling video on the streaming.

Is it possible to somehow programmatically disable all notifications or do I have to ask the user to do so by himself?

Comment: I sure hope that's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control notifications from other apps. There is indeed [a solution for rooted devices](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2217572).

'Standards' part in [this guide](https://www.objc.io/issues/11-android/android-notifications/) says:

> One of the unfortunate problems Android users face is that there is no
>   centralized control for how notifications work. This means that if
>   there is an application prompting you with a notification, short of
>   uninstalling the application, there isn’t much you can do. Starting in
>   Android 4.1, users received a buried binary setting to 'Turn off
>   notifications’ for a specific app.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately not. Perhaps on rooted devices, but ¯_(ツ)_/¯. Best way seems to navigate the user to the related setting to disable all notifications, as you have also mentioned.